# What error is in this Alexa intent that uses API?

Tags: javascript, json, alexa-skills-kit

I am doing a simple project that aims to compare coronavirus cases between two different countries. The input from the user will be something like "Are confirmed cases in America higher than in France?" and the intent will speakoutput either a yes or a no based on whether the data obtained from the API tallies with the assumption made by the user. The problem is I'm new to coding and I can't see the problem that causes the error which stops the whole intent from functioning. The intent code is as follows:

```
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GetTaskThreeIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
    
        var country_one = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slot.c_one.value
        var country_two = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slot.c_two.value
        var compare = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slot.compare.value
        var criteria = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slot.criteria.value
        var URLc1 = "https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/" + country_one
        var URLc2 = "https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/" + country_two
        var x, y, a, datac1, datac2, i, j
     
        var response1 = await getHttps(URLc1)
        var data1 = JSON.parse(response1)
        var response2 = await getHttps(URLc2)
        var data2 = JSON.parse(response2)
        var n1 = data1.length
        var n2 = data2.length
        var speakOutput
        
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            
            if (i === n1){
                
                if (criteria === "death cases"){
            datac1 = data1[n1].Deaths 
                }
                
            else if (criteria === "death rates"){
            datac1 = (data1[n1].Deaths/data1[n1].Confirmed) * 100
                }
                
            else{
            datac1 = data1[n1].Confirmed
                }
        } 
            
        }
        
        for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
            
            if (j === n2){
                
                if (criteria === "death cases"){
            datac2 = data2[n2].Deaths 
                }
                
            else if (criteria === "death rates"){
            datac2 = (data2[n2].Deaths/data2[n2].Confirmed) * 100
                }
                
            else{
            datac2 = data2[n2].Confirmed
                }
        }
            
        }
        
        
        
        if (compare === "higher"){
            x = 1
        }
        else{
            x = 0
        }
        
        if (datac1 > datac2){
            y = 1
            a = "higher"
        }
        else {
            y = 0
            a = "lower"
        }
    
    if (x === y){
        speakOutput = "Your assumption was correct. The " + criteria + " in " + country_one + " is " + data1 + " which is " + a + " than in " + country_two + " which has " + data2 + criteria
       
    }
    else {
             speakOutput = "Your assumption was not correct. The " + criteria + " in " + country_one + " is " + data1 + " which is " + a + " than in " + country_two + " which has " + data2 + criteria
        }
        
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Comment: There could be any number of things going on. Are you using the Alexa-hosted option for hosting your code? If so, in the Code tab, click the CloudWatch Logs icon near the top. That will open an AWS CloudWatch list of log results from your test runs, newest at the top. Open the newest and see if any errors are being logged. You can also add `console.log()` statements to your code to log out values to CloudWatch and see if you're getting the inputs you think you are.

Comment: Also, what's handling `getHttps`? That's not a standard command in JavaScript. Are you creating that function globally outside of the intent handler? Did you mean `https.get` from Node's built-in https package? Are you requiring the package elsewhere?